# flask, tornado http2 how to support

Tags: python-3.x

How can flask and tornado support both http1.1 and Http2 in python3?
Which library is more recommended?

```py
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import options

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
self.write("Hello, world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = tornado.web.Application(\[(r"/", MainHandler)\])
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, ssl_options={
"certfile": "/path/to/your/certificate.crt",
"keyfile": "/path/to/your/private.key",
"ssl_version": options.ssl_options.ssl_version,
"ciphers": options.ssl_options.ciphers,
"alpn_protocols": \["h2", "http/1.1"\]
})
server.listen(443)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

# AttributeError: Unrecognized option 'ssl-options'. Did you mean: '\_options'?
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Your question is clearly opinion based. I suggest you to read [ask] and take the [tour] to make your question be not opinion based